# Examples of totally real minimal submanifolds in complex space forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

If we have $R^{4}$ with basis $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}=Je_{1},e_{4}=Je_{2}\}$, then we know that $\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$ is totally real minimal submanifold of $R^{4}$. Is there a nontrivial example of totally real minimal submanifold of $R^{4}$.

Also, the above totally real minimal immersion is an inclusion map. How we can write a basis of a submanifold in the case when the immersion $f:R^{2}\to R^{4}$ is defined as $f:(x,y)\to (x,y,x,y)$.

Comment: Could you give some motivation or context for your first question? Also, I do not understand your second question, what is a basis of a submanifold?

Comment: Yes, motivation is Proposition 1 of the paper "On totally real submanifolds", Ognian T. Kassabov. I would like to see some example (nontrivial) of a manifold in the assertion. For the second question,  trivial minimal totally real immersion is an inclusion $f:(x,y)\to (x,y,0,0)$, that is $\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$ is a totally real minimal submanifold of $R^{4}$.

Comment: Do you mean a basis as a vector space? Then this is not a question for MO! Moreover you seem to be confusing $\{\ \}$ and $\langle\ \rangle$. I feel you did not think through your question enough before asking, you should rethink it and edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many such examples.

A totally real submanifold in this case is simply a surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ such that, for each $p\in S$, the space $J(T_pS)$ is orthogonal to $T_pS$.  In other words, if $x^i$ are the coordinates dual to your basis $e_i$, then the $2$-form $\Upsilon_1 = dx^1\wedge dx^3 + dx^2\wedge dx^4$ should vanish on $S$.  Suppose that we also require that the $2$-form $\Upsilon_2 = dx^1\wedge dx^4 - dx^2\wedge dx^3$ should vanish on $S$.  These are equivalent to the vanishing of 
$$
\Upsilon_1 + i\,\Upsilon_2 = (dx^1 - i\,dx^2)\wedge (dx^3 + i\,dx^4) = dz^1\wedge dz^2
$$
where $z^1 = x^1-i x^2$ and $z^2 = x^3+ix^4$ are complex coordinates with respect to a different complex structure $J'$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$ than the one you defined, but that is also orthogonal with respect to the underlying metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Any $J'$-complex curve (and there are many of them, just take $z^2 = h(z^1)$ where $h$ is holomorphic, for example), is then an example of a surface on which $\Upsilon$ vanishes.  All $J'$-complex curves are minimal (since $J'$ is orthogonal), so this furnishes many examples of nontrivial totally real minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand your example. Does vanishing of $\gamma_{1}$ mean that the immersion from S to $R^{4}$ is holomorphic? Is there some paper where I can find this example or similar? Does choice of a complex structure determine is surface minimal or not?

Comment: @NovakDjokovic: 'Upsilon' ($\Upsilon$), not 'gamma' ($\gamma$). The vanishing of $\Upsilon_1$ does *not* make the immersion holomorphic, just totally real with respect to the complex unitary structure you described.  The vanishing of *both* $\Upsilon_1$ and $\Upsilon_2$ is equivalent to the *image* surface being holomorphic with respect to the complex structure $J'$.  The *metric* $g$ determines whether a surface is minimal (with respect to $g$) or not, but complex curves with respect to a $g$-orthogonal complex structure are always $g$-minimal. Try Lawson's *Lectures on Minimal Submanifolds*.